# Max Cardinality Integer Programming Problem

Tags: integer-programming, network-flow

I browsed a lot on google to find any similar solution to my problem below, particularly on network flow literature, but couldn't find any similar problems. I think my problem can be probably solved by an appropriate integer programming formulation, but I can't exactly figure it out either.

Suppose I have $m$ number of variables, along with a matrix of weights between every one variables to another:

$\begin{matrix} & |  & N_1  & N_2 & ... & N_m\\ \_ & \_  & \_  & \_ & \_ & \_ \\ N_1 & |  & 0  & w_{1,2} & ... & w_{1, m}\\ N_2 & |  & w_{1, 2}  & 0 & ... & w_{2, m}\\ ... & |  & ... & ... & ... & ... \\ N_m & |  & w_{1, m}  & w_{2, m} & ... & 0
\end{matrix}$

where $w_{i, j} = w_{j, i}$ (and if needed $0 \le |w_{j, i}| \le 1$).

I want to choose a set of maximum number of variables $\{N_k\}$ out of $m$ variables such that the weights $w_{k_1, k_2}$ between any $N_{k_1}$ and $N_{k_2}$ selected in the set $\{N_k\}$ satisfy:

$-\beta \le w_{j, i} \le \beta$.

where $\beta$ is a constant provided to the problem (and if needed, $|\beta|$ < 1, otherwise we can obviously choose all the $m$ variables).

Can someone help me if this can be solved (or reformulated) into any known network flow problem, or alternatively, if there is an easy way to frame this into an integer programming problem ?

So far, I have been able to write:

$\max \sum_{k=1}^m X_k$

$s.t.$

$ -\beta \le w_{i,j} X_i X_j \le \beta$    $\forall i, j$

But I can't figure out how to separate out the $X_i X_j$ into a linear way (to use any Integer Programming package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weights are entirely irrelevant. After receiving your $\beta$ any $w_{i, j}$ with $-\beta \leq w_{i, j} \leq \beta$ is an edge and any $N_k$ is a vertex, forming a graph.

Then your problem is simply [finding the maximum clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs).

Comment: Thanks. I checked the link you mentioned, but I doesn't look like the greedy approach would give me an optimal solution. Suppose $\beta = 0.5$ and 4 vertices: A, B, C and D. Consider one vertex A already in the clique, where the weights between 3 other B, C, D vertices are $w_{b,c} = 0.6$, $w_{b,d} = 0.6$, $w_{c,d} = 0.3$, along with $w_{a,b} = w_{a,c} = w_{a,d} = 0.1$. If I choose the next vertex to be B, then I wouldn't be able to selected C or D (and my answer would be {A, B}). But I if select the next vertex to be C, then I can still select D (and my answer would be {A, C, D}.

Comment: **Maximum** clique, not just a maximal clique.  This is a hard problem in general (NP-complete).

Comment: I am not so worried about the NP-complete part (with today's fast computers), but I was wondering is there any integer programming formulation (or any other exponential time solution) to this problem ? Would you know if the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm mentioned in the link above solve the problem or is it also an approximation?

Comment: Bron-Kerbosch is exact, but it finds all maximal cliques, not just a maximum clique.  At least one of those that it finds will be a maximum clique, but you may have to sift through a huge amount of output to find it.

Comment: An integer linear programming formulation is: maximize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to $x_i + x_j = 1$ for each pair $(i,j)$ that is not an edge, all $x_i \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @uday Sorry, I linked to the wrong paragraph in the article, fixed it to maximum.

Comment: Thanks Orson for your help. Before your and Robert’s replies,I couldn’t even figure out if this problem had a name.

Comment: @RobertIsrael , thanks for your help. would the constraint be $x_i + x_j <= 1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant.